# describing end points of a range in British English

Tags: british-english, range-inclusion

I'd like to know whether "inclusive" can be placed after "between March and July," as after "from March to July" to indicate March and July are included in the range in British English.

And how do we express the opposite idea that the two ends are not included in the range? From March to July exclusive? Between March and July exclusive?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

**I'd like to know whether "inclusive" can be placed after "between March and July," as after "from March to July" to indicate March and July are included in the range in British English.**

We would not normally say Between March and July. We would say **From March to July** and it would be inclusive.

If you do not want it to be inclusive say **from April to June**

However, this is in relation to months Other situations may use a range with inclusive or not inclusive.

Link to an example[English website](https://www.talk-english.co.uk/talk-english-network-pilot-march-to-july-2017/)

Comment: Thank you, but I just want to know whether "between X and Y inclusive" is natural English. If this is unnatural with months, is it possible with something else?